# GitLab community edition WebHook Support

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to achieve CICD using Jenkins, GitLab and AWS services.

I have configured Jenkins correctly, but I did not found any option for WebHook in GitLab.

I am using community edition . Does community edition supports WebHook ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Gitlab repository, on the settings button at the top right click "Integrations" :

[image]

Then edit trigger event and webhook URL as :

```
https://<jenkins-host>:<port>/project/<your job>
```

[image]